# Динамическая смена языка ios приложения

Tags: ios, objective-c

Есть в приложении смена языка, и чтобы он менялся сразу, без перезагрузки приложения.
С файлами .storyboard понятно можно перегрузить так:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[[MALocalizationSystem sharedLocalizationSystem] getBundle] ];

    [self presentViewController:[sb instantiateInitialViewController] animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Это если экран создается в Interface builder. Но проблема в том что есть экран, который появляется при первом запуске и он предлагает выбрать язык.
Он создается вручную (без использования .storyboard, все руками в коде).
Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы сменить язык и попасть на следующий экран, без перезапуска приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Ты меняешь язык через

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];` ?

Тогда в каждом контроллере в методе viewWillAppear бери текущий язык и вручную обновляй строчки. Localized.strings можно взять с помощью NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle.

Т.к. ты сам записываешь язык в NSUserDefaults, то сможешь и найти путь к нужному `Localized.strings`. Или, как вариант, сделай несколько бандлов (по одному для каждого языка) с одним лишь файлом - `Localized.strings`. Тогда строки можно будет получать через `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`.

Comment: Да для смены беру
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ru",@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

а потом текст использую такой
`MALocalizedString(@"Адрес вашей почты", nil)`
где


`#define MALocalizedString(key, comment) [[MALocalizationSystem sharedLocalizationSystem] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:(comment)]`

Comment: а сама функция

`- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)comment
{
    return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:comment table:nil];
}`